# If $a$ conjugates with $b$, then $a^{-1}$ conjugates with $b^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a$ conjugates with $b$, then $a^{-1}$ conjugates with $b^{-1}$ in a group $G.$
This seems like a pretty trivial statement but I'm trying to figure out how to prove it. So far I have that if $b=gag^{-1},$ * $b^{-1}=g^{-1}a^{-1}g,$ but we want **  $b^{-1}=ga^{-1}g^{-1}.$ Are * and ** equivalent?

Comment: Contemporary use is more often "$a$ is conjugate to $b$"...

Comment: Seconded. I didn't want to use different wording in my answer from what the question said, but writing "$a$ is conjugate to $b$" would have felt far more natural to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful:

- "$a$ conjugates with $b$" means "there is a $g$ such that $b=gag^{-1}$".
- "$a^{-1}$ conjugates with $b^{-1}$" means "there is a $g$ such that $b^{-1}=ga^{-1}g^{-1}$".

However, these are separate definitions, so when both of these statements are in play at the same time, the $g$'s don't have to be the same. For the purposes of clarity, it is better to pick a second variable in the second statement. That is, you are assuming there is a $g$ such that $b=gag^{-1}$; you want to prove there is an $h$ such that $b^{-1} = ha^{-1}h^{-1}$.

If you've shown that $b^{-1} = g^{-1} a^{-1}g$, then you have done this! Let $h = g^{-1}$: now you have $b^{-1} = ha^{-1}h^{-1}$.

P.S. Having read user2661923's answer, I now believe that if you think you've shown $b^{-1} = g^{-1}a^{-1}g$ from $b = gag^{-1}$ you've made a mistake (which is a separate issue); you should actually be getting $b^{-1} = ga^{-1}g^{-1}$ with *the same* $g$. On the other hand, from $b = gag^{-1}$ you can get $a = g^{-1}bg$, which can help you prove that if $a$ conjugates with $b$, then $b$ conjugates with $a$.

Answer (score 2):

In Group Theory, $(rs)^{-1} = s^{-1} \times r^{-1}.$

Therefore, if you start with the equation:

$$b = ga\left(g^{-1}\right), \tag1 $$

then you can simply take the inverse of both sides.

That is, if $r = s$, then $r^{-1} = s^{-1}.$

So, taking the inverse of both sides of (1) above yields

$$b^{-1} = g\left(a^{-1}\right)g^{-1}.$$